# Using Xcode and WKWebView I have a 1sec white screen while the webview loads. How can I stop this and only display webview when loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have made a simple webView app to show a web responsive website. I have built a launch screen and written code below. (*2) Between the launch screen and webView I can see a white screen for 1-2 seconds. I have searched stack overflow and found 2 solutions that are below but I do not know how to implement them. Please may someone use my code and provide an example of how to do this? (*1)

(*1)
solution 1.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad]; //objWebView is the outlet of UIWebView
        [objWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body style=\"background-color:black;\"></body></html>" baseURL:nil];

        //the more the delay the errors will be less so within 0.1-0.3 would be fine
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadURL:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]; 
    }

-(void)loadURL:(id)sender{
    [objWebView stopLoading]; //added this line to stop the previous request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [objWebView loadRequest:req];
```

solution 2;

```
// load index.html 
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
self.webview.delegate = self;

self.webview.alpha = 0; // flicker fix 

[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

Add this to delegate after loading
// flicker fix

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView  
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30];

    self.webview.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

(*2)My code

```
import UIKit

import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView()
        container.addSubview(webView)
    }     

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, container.bounds.width, container.bounds.height)

        webView.frame = frame

        loadRequest("WebUrlGoesHere")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
     }

func loadRequest(urlStr: String) {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)


}
```

( very sorry about how the code has copied over )

Comment: What would you like to display while the web view loads?

Comment: I would like to display an imageView in future I may look to add progress indicators or login. But for now I can simply use a single ImageView.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?